# Benefit of Initialization List - Avoiding calls to default constructors

Tags: c++

I was reading effective C++ and I couldn't really understand one of the mentioned benefit of initialization list.From what I understand is that initialization lists also help to avoid calling of unnecessary default constructors especially when they are not needed. So in order to test that I created a simple code example as such

```
class base
{
public:

    base()
    {
        std::cout << "Default Constructor called \n";
    }
    base (int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Int constructor called \n";
    }
};

class der : public base
{
private:
    base b;
public:
    der(int i):b(i)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived constructor called \n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    der d(12);
}
```

No where I assumed that only the int constructor will be called instead both the constructors of the base class are called. Could anyone please clarify this concept.

Comment: You should try simpler examples first, I think...

Comment: @KerrekSB Instead of criticizing and down-voting instantly maybe you could have cleared this up.

Comment: @Casper_2211: I don't mean this to be critical. Rather, I think the OP would genuinely have a more enjoyable learning experience if they had tried, say, something like `base b1; base b2(12);` first and convinced themselves of the workings of that one class before moving on to derived classes. The point is, there's a ton you can learn by playing around with small variations of code, and that sort of learning usually has much greater impact than leaping straight to asking someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you actually have 2 instances of `base`, one as a member and one as a base. Either change into `der(int i):base(i),b(i)` or remove the member.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you are adding a member of type `base` to the `der` class, which also needs to be constructed. That member is being initialized with the constructor that doesn't take arguments. What you probably meant was:

```
class base
{
private:
    int num;
public:

    base()
    {
        std::cout << "Default Constructor called \n";
    }
    base (int i) : num(i)
    {
        std::cout << "Int constructor called \n";
    }
};

class der : public base
{
private:
    //base b;
public:
    der(int i):base(i)
    {
        std::cout << "Derived constructor called \n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    der d(12);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`der` has two `base instances`, as explained by Ylisar. **As base has default constructor, it will be implicitly called in der constructor.**

Also C++ only supports below two forms of main function, there is no `void main()` in C++

**§3.6.1 Main function**

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function
>   shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but
>   otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations
>   shall allow both of the following definitions of main:
>
> int main() { /* ... */ }
>
> and
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }

Answer (score 0):

In your der,There are two base class, one is for inheriting, another one is b(the member of der).